# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in tty

Tags: boot, 18.04, tty, display-manager

I'm not able to start my GUI.
I exited from some server via exit command after which I restarted my computer and then it moved to tty console.
[error after restarting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RChpf.png)
I tried following solutions:

- Function keys only take me from tty1-6.
- I am not even able to connect to network, though my LAN is connected and has working internet.
  I also tried following commands, nothing works-

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo systemctl restart gdm3

My display is gdm3.
I also tried booting from grub, that also failed.
After all, I tried installing fresh ubuntu, it doesn't even go to boot menu(F12 was of no help) and could not install Ubuntu also.

Please help, what can I do next?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the `startx` command (as a regular user).

Comment: @Jos I tried startx too, doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when you enter `startx` - you must get a load of messages, some good, maybe some bad. What are the relevant ones? Error messages put out by `startx` start with `(EE)`. Just "doesnt'work" tells us nothing.

Comment: output of startx command-  *xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (operation not permitted) xinit:connection to X server lost.